# Raspberry Pi segmentation fault - Python

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a program on my Raspberry Pi written on Python that I use to control 2 motors. Here is some of the code :

```
def fullLeft() :
    speed1 = motor1Speed
    speed2 = motor2Speed
    setMotor1Speed(100)
    setMotor2Speed(-100)
    while io.input(forward1Control) and io.input(backward2Control) :
            print( "%d : %d" %(motor1Speed,motor2Speed))
    stop()
    setMotor1Speed(speed1)
    setMotor2Speed(speed2)
    print("Left Done")

def fullRight() :
    speed1 = motor1Speed
    speed2 = motor2Speed
    setMotor1Speed(-100)
    setMotor2Speed(100)
    while io.input(forward2Control) and io.input(backward1Control) :
            print( "%d : %d" %(motor1Speed,motor2Speed))
    stop()
    setMotor1Speed(speed1)
    setMotor2Speed(speed2)
    print("Right  Done")

def stop () :
    io.output(forward1Out,False)
    motor1Forward.stop()
    io.output(backward1Out, False)
    motor1Backward.stop()
    io.output(forward2Out, False)
    motor2Forward.stop()
    io.output(backward2Out, False)
    motor2Backward.stop()
    global motor1Speed
    motor1Speed = 0
    global motor2Speed
    motor2Speed = 0
```

Everything worked well before I introduce the `stop()` function on the `fullRight()` method. The problem is that `fullLeft()` works perfectly but after the 2nd while loop on the `fullRight()` function, I have the error `Segmentation Fault` and the program crashes. I don't know what to do and why is this happening. Can someone help me to figure out what the problem is...

Comment: Don't motor1speed and motor2speed need to be declared as global in fullRight and fullLeft?

Comment: @Josh - No. They would only need to be declared global if they are being assigned to.

Comment: @Robᵩ +1^ that's my bad

Comment: @Josh The problem isn't due to something like that, I'm sure. The problem only happened when I added `stop()` on `fullRight()` everything else is just fine.